# Razor cshtml - wrong tabs/indentation in helper method calls with objects as arguments

Tags: c#, razor, auto-indent

In the razor views for my project (C# in Visual Studio 2015), I have several helper methods at the top of the file. Further down, the automatic formatting is giving me incorrect indentation in method calls that look like this:

```
<div>
    @SomeHelperMethodCall( new SomeObjectToPass(
{
    SomeProperty = "Some Value",
    AnotherProperty = "Another value"
} )
</div>
```

What I want is this:

```
<div>
    @SomeHelperMethodCall( new SomeObjectToPass(
    {
        SomeProperty = "Some Value",
        AnotherProperty = "Another value"
    } )
</div>
```

It gets even worse if one of the properties is also a newly-instantiated object, losing two indents:

```
        <div>
            @SomeHelperMethodCall( new SomeObjectToPass(
        {
            SomeProperty = "Some Value",
            AnotherProperty = "Another value",
            SomeObjectProperty = new ObjectName() 
{
    PropertyName = "value"
}
        } )
        </div>
```

Is this a bug? I've looked through the options for code formatting and I can't find any that handle new objects in method calls with properties on their own lines. I've looked in the options for both C# and HTML.

I'm not using any fancy addons like ReSharper, just plain VS2015. The issue persists even if/when I auto-format the entire document.

Also, I'm not 100% sure, but the existence of @helpers in the file itself (rather than partials) seems to have something to do with this issue showing up.

Comment: Razor indentation is definitely finicky - but if it's tabbing backwards that much it sounds like you have an unclosed tag somewhere above it (whether C# or HTML)

Comment: I looked through the file, and I didn't find any prior to the first instance of the issue above (which happened to be inside one of the helpers (which calls another helper), if that means anything). These are all before any lines of HTML. There were no HTML tags inside of _that_ helper, either, and all of the braces are closed properly.

Comment: it could also be a missing closed tag afterwards - however without seeing the contents of the file this is occurring on I can only speculate that this is the issue

Comment: Unfortunately this file has ballooned to over 8000 lines over the last few months, but I will keep unclosed tags in mind while I try to figure this one out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried collapsing your tags to verify whether there is a missing closing tag or not?